# Tunning treshold in Binarizer to BernoulliNB() classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, naivebayes

I want to use the BernoulliNB() classifier, and my data is not binarized. So I want to choose the best binarization threshold by GridsearchCV().
My code looks like:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.preprocessing import Binarizer

pipeline = Pipeline([('binarizer', Binarizer()), ('classifier', BernoulliNB())])
params = {'estimator__binarizer__threshold': np.logspace(0, 5, 20)}

clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=params, cv=5, refit=True)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
clf.best_estimator_.score(X_test, y_test)
```

It gives me error:

```
ValueError: Check the list of available parameters with estimator.get_params().keys().
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: `estimator__binarizer__treshold` should be `estimator__binarizer__threshold`. Spelling of `"threshold"` is wrong.

Comment: That was not a reason. It still gives me this error: ValueError: Invalid parameter estimator for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('binarizer', Binarizer(copy=True, threshold=0.0)), ('classifier', BernoulliNB(alpha=1.0, binarize=0.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for this purpose - *edit & update* your post instead!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my bad. In the comment, I just spotted the spelling mistake of `'treshold'` and in a hurry, did not give attention to estimator part.

For a pipeline, the parameters can be accessed by using the two parts:

1. Name of the steps like `binarizer` or `classifier` here
2. Actual param name for that particular name from step 1.

You dont need to append `estimator` to the above parts. So in your case, you will need to use the following:

```
params = {'binarizer__threshold': np.logspace(0, 5, 20)}
```

to access the `'threshold'` param of the `'binarizer'` step of pipeline.